# How to find a variable value from a recursive method?

Tags: java, methods, implicit-conversion

I need help finding the value from the variable `v`. This method comes from an exercise that I was trying to do. It asked for the return value from this input: `m(2, "43912");`

I did a `System.out.print` on my `main()` to show the return value:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    System.out.println(m(2,"43912"));
}
```

the Output of this : `CDEF21912`

I understand the `CDEF` part and the `219` part, what I just don't understand is why `v` returns as `12`.

```
static int m(int i, String s) {   
  int v = 0;   
  System.out.print((char)(i+'A'));   
  if (i < s.length()) {   
    char c = s.charAt(i);    
    v = m(i + 1, s) + c - '0';     
    System.out.print(c);     
  }     
  return v;     
}
```

Comment: To get better understanding about that it is good idea to debug you method and check each step of execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Step1:
  print:C  
Step2:
  print:D
Step3:
  print:E  
Step4:
  print:F  at the same time, finishing function m  and return v=0
Step5:
  i=4,c=2,v=0+'2'-'0',print 2 and return v=2
Step6:
  i=3,c=1,v=2+'1'-'0',print 1 and return v=3
Step7:
  i=2,c=9,v=3+'9'-'0',print 9 and return v=12
```

Until now the print is "CDEF219",then is will execute System.out.println(12),you know the last return of function m (from Step7),so 12 will be added to "CDEF219",and the result becomes "CDEF21912".next time ,you can use breaking point to help you understand.Hope my answer can help you.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much, got one last question, why do we need the '0' when we are calculating "v" ?

Comment: Beacause in ascii table char '0' equals 48 ,char '1' equals 49 and char '2' equals 50...,if you don't minus '0' ,"v=0+'2' "will get 50.